# Spring JpaSpecificationExecutor new query method NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring` and `JpaRepository` as data access layer. I have my `@Repository` interface as below:

```
@Repository
interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event> {
    .... some custom methods irrelevant to this post ....
}
```

Here's my simplified model classes:

```
class Event {
    Long eventID;
    String name;
    Date time;
    Zone zone;
}


class Zone {
    Long zoneId;
    String zoneName;
    User user;
}


class User {
    Long userId;
    String username;
}
```

I'm using there `JpaSpecificationExecutor` to fetch database for list of `Event`s in specific `time`. I'm using this method and it work correctly:

```
Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

But I want to add another condition to fetch entries only for specific `User`.

I tried to create new method like this:

```
Page<Event> findAllByZone_User(User user, Specification<Event> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

But when I call it I get in this line Exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
```

Is it even possible to create such method? If not - how should I proceed?

Comment: Can you try  findByZoneUser(User user)

Comment: @barath but what about `Specification` and `Pageable`?

Comment: Try findByZoneUser(User user, Specification<Event> spec, Pageable pageable)

Comment: @CIPHER007 the same error as with `findAllByZone_User`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `Spring boot project` like yours and this is working for me. You can check my code below.....

**Event.java**

```
    package com.example.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long eventID;
    private String name;
    private Date time = new Date();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Zone zone;

    public Long getEventID() {
        return eventID;
    }
    public void setEventID(Long eventID) {
        this.eventID = eventID;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public Zone getZone() {
        return zone;
    }
    public void setZone(Zone zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }
}
```

**Zone.java**

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Zone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long zoneId;
    private String zoneName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

    public Long getZoneId() {
        return zoneId;
    }
    public void setZoneId(Long zoneId) {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
    }
    public String getZoneName() {
        return zoneName;
    }
    public void setZoneName(String zoneName) {
        this.zoneName = zoneName;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;
    private String username;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

and my repositories are

**EventRepository.java**

```
package com.example.model;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event>{

    Page<Event> findAllByZoneUser(User user, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.example.model;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

I am calling repository methods directly in my controller like below

**UserController.java**

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    EventRepository eventRepository;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Object> updateUserDO(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "eventID");
        map.put("user", eventRepository.findAllByZoneUser(user, pageRequest));
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get the same result after minor changes in my repository and controller `Page<Event> findAllByZoneUserUserId(Long userId, Pageable pageable);`  and in my controller remove `User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);` and change `eventRepository.findAllByZoneUser(user, pageRequest)` to `eventRepository.findAllByZoneUserUserId(userId, pageRequest)`

Comment: After these changes you have no need to create `UserRepository.java`

Comment: thank you for your example, it works but when I add `Specification<Event>` as method parameter it stops working. I resolved issue by adding filtering by user inside my class which is implementing `Specification<>` interface